# Creating AMP friendly website in an existing website

Tags: html, css, amp-html

I have a dynamic blogging website built on NodeJS and Bootstrap 4. The website currently has about 8 JS files and 5 CSS files. It is responsive.

I'm trying to implement AMP but it's throwing all the AMP errors.

My question is: 
I cannot remove those JS & CSS files because that's use for Desktop version. How then should I go ahead? Is there a way that I could ask AMP to ignore the desktop CSS and JS files?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use your own JavaScript with AMP. You'll have to remove your JavaScript files and use the elements available within the AMP framework itself.

Here you can find a complete list of AMP components:
https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components

And examples for some of them here:
https://ampbyexample.com/#components

About your CSS: You can't use external stylesheets, you'll have to include them inline. Also note that your CSS has to be smaller than 50kb.

Comment: Thanks. After going through it, I realize I have to create a new amp website `amp.example.com` and can't use the existing website! They should have mentioned this in the first line of the AMP Project website in bright red bold color.